# How to run this only once after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#b').datepicker().on('changeDate', recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_field').change(recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_field_type').change(recalculate_deadline);

    $('#id_other_field').change(check_reminder_date);
    $('#id_time').datepicker().on('hide', check_reminder_date); #this

});
```

How to run this only once after page load?

```
$('#id_time').datepicker().on('hide', check_reminder_date);
```

For now If I change date, this function - "check_reminder_date" is running.
I want to run this only once after page load, after user can change date manualy(without check_reminder_date function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a handler only once, you can use `one()` instead of `on()`:

```
$('#id_time').datepicker().one('hide', check_reminder_date);
```

[See this page](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for more info.

Comment: Ok. I added: $('#id_time').datepicker().one('hide', check_reminder_date); and now it is run only once, but my value is override by today date. I don't know why. Full code here: http://dpaste.com/hold/996248/

Comment: This is a different issue, so I'd advise that you make it a separate question with more details on the check_reminder_date function itself.